# What does `utf-8` charset change in a `multipart/form-data` HTTP request?

Tags: http, post, file-upload, encoding, utf-8

In an attempt to upload a binary file to a web server, I observed that by setting the `Content-Type` header to a value with `charset="utf-8"` present, the POST request data integrity fails.

Chrome seems to omit all `charset` attributes in both the header and the body while performing a file upload POST request all together.

However, some web servers satisfy the request correctly if the `charset="utf-8"` attribute is included.

**Working Example:**

```
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----FormBoundary

------FormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileupload"; filename="data.bin"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

------FormBoundary--

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

The file was received successfully.
```

**Failing Example:**

```
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Content-type: multipart/form-data; charset="utf-8"; boundary=----FormBoundary

------FormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileupload"; filename="data.bin"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

------FormBoundary--

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

The uploaded file seems to be broken.
```

The addition of the `charset="utf-8"` seems to make some web servers fail to decode uploaded data correctly, while it doesn't seem to affect the process in other web servers.

Please note that in both cases, including the charset after the `application/octet-stream` type does not affect anything, I'm rather focusing on the addition after the `multipart/form-data` type.

What happens in the server when the Unicode charset flag is present after the multipart type?

Comment: Interesting question. The [media type registration](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/multipart/form-data) does not foresee a charset param. Complying implementations should hence ignore it.

Comment: Good question. Though default encoding of `multipart/form-data` should be defined as hidden `_charset_` field, or `<form>` element's `accept-charset` attribute. Please check https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578#section-5.1.2 for details.