# Full file doesn't upload on Retrofit2

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I have a fragment where,  I click on Browse Button and open file manager and select the file and send it to server via POST Retrofit2.

I get the success message 200. The file is listed in server but it wont open.  **The size is 1kb**.  So, I think the file is not properly uploaded.

Following is my code.

Where am I going wrong?

```
            File origFile = new File(PathHolder);
            String getDirPath = origFile.getParent();
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), getDirPath);
            multipartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploadFiles",origFile.getName(),requestFile);

            new UploadFileAsyncTask().execute();
```

And the async task is

```
protected notificationVO doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    notificationVO res;
                    WebserviceImpl webservices = new WebserviceImpl();
                    res = webservices.notifyAttachment(token,multipartBody, getContext());

                    Log.e("File","browse uploaded");
                    return res;
        }
```

Api

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    public Call<notificationVO>notifyAttachment(@Query("token")String token,
                                                @Part MultipartBody.Part attachFile);   // @Part MultipartBody.Part file
```

Implementation

```
 public notificationVO notifyAttachment(String token,MultipartBody.Part fileUri,final Context context){

        WebservicesApi mRestAPIWService = ApiUtilsForWS.getAPIService(context,);


        Call<notificationVO> call = mRestAPIWService.notifyAttachment(token,fileUri);
        try {

            Response<notificationVO> response = call.execute();
            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"Success."+response.code());
                return response.body();

            }
            else
            {

                Log.e(TAG,"Failed."+response.code());
                return null;
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check from postman(postman rest client) to upload a file using same API

Comment: Perfectly uploading from postman.. The problem is in Android code.

Comment: I will post an answer for this before that please check the size of file that you are uploading.

Comment: around 180 kb.... it goes perfectly well from postman.. and even downloads from server....  the issue can be of the RequestBody... where charset utf is added....      Content Type: Media Type : multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8     I dont know if this is the issue or not, but here is the link.                                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045952/what-does-utf-8-charset-change-in-a-multipart-form-data-http-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interface like this below, remove @Query annotation add as @Part in your interface.

```
interface Service {
            @Multipart
            @POST("upload")
            Call<notificationVO> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("token") RequestBody name);
        }
```

Check your File path is valid and also check the file size to confirm that you are getting file properly from your file picker.

```
File origFile = new File(PathHolder);
int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(origFile .length()/1024));
```

If everything is OK then try this below option to upload your file it will work

```
RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), mFile);
        RequestBody token = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
// Service is interface name you can use your own interface name
        Service uploadImage = retrofit.create(Service.class);
        Call<notificationVO> fileUpload = uploadImage.postImage(fileToUpload, token);
        fileUpload.enqueue(new Callback<notificationVO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<notificationVO> call, Response<notificationVO> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<notificationVO> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanku.. but it's not working.. the file is seen in the server but only 1 kB size...

Comment: It worked.. thanks... my code worked to but I had added getParent() bcz of which it was not working.

Comment: Welcome :-) :-)

Comment: Will check it and send you answer